# Print sysout lines at single go from open 3

Tags: perl

I am using open 3 and printing lines as below one by one after doing some parsing. I do not want to print line by line I want to store and print at once How can i do it?

```
while(my $nextLine=<HANDLE_OUT>) {       
    chomp($nextLine);  
    if ($nextLine =~ m!<BEA-!){
        print "Skipping this line (BEA): |$nextLine|\n" if $debug;
    }
    print $nextLine."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want any lines to be printed while you're looping over the file handle, I would do something like this:

The data structure being a hash of anonymous arrays( debug and output ).

```
my %handle_output = ( 
    debug => [], 
    output => [], 
); 


while(my $nextLine=<HANDLE_OUT>) {       
    chomp($nextLine);  
    if ($nextLine =~ m!<BEA-!){
       push( @{$handle_out{debug}}, $line ) if $debug;
    } else {
        push @{$handle_output{output}}, $line;
    }
}
for my $line ( @{$handle_output{output}} ) {
    print $line . "\n";
}
```

Comment: What if i use backticks something like

Answer (score 1):

You just want to store it in a variable and then print it? Just append it to a variable in the loop. Or am I misunderstanding?

```
my $out = '';
while(my $nextLine=<HANDLE_OUT>) {       
    chomp($nextLine);  
    if ($nextLine =~ m!<BEA-!){
        print "Skipping this line (BEA): |$nextLine|\n" if $debug;
        next;  # I'm guessing you don't want to include these lines, either
    }
    $out .= $nextLine."\n";
}
print $out;
```